# Android RecyclerView and CardView LayoutManager always crash in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

my app always crash,i try to access a fragment that displays a cardview using RecyclerView.

Here is my Fragment

```
public class Fragmentone extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<TestBean> listItem;
    private RecyclerAdapter adapter;


    public Fragmentone() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmentone, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        initData();

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(listItem,getActivity());
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    private void initData() {
        listItem = new ArrayList<>();

        listItem.add(new TestBean("佛山傻逼酒店","二月17号","二月18号","600","已付款"));

    }

}
```

and this is my adapter

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ListViewHolder> {
    private List<TestBean> listitem;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<TestBean> listitem, Context context) {

        this.listitem = listitem;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_item, viewGroup, false);
        ListViewHolder listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder(v);
        return listViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int i) {
        holder.tv_roomfee.setText(listitem.get(i).getRoomfee());
        holder.tv_hotelname.setText(listitem.get(i).getHotelname());
        holder.tv_liststate.setText(listitem.get(i).getListstate());
        holder.tv_checkindate.setText(listitem.get(i).getCheckindate());
        holder.tv_lastcheckindate.setText(listitem.get(i).getLastcheckindate());

        holder.btn_paynow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        holder.btn_cancellist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listitem.size();
    }

    public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView id_cardview;

        TextView tv_roomfee;
        TextView tv_liststate;
        TextView tv_hotelname;
        TextView tv_checkindate;
        TextView tv_lastcheckindate;

        Button btn_paynow;
        Button btn_cancellist;

        public ListViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            id_cardview = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_cardview);
            tv_roomfee = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_roomfee);
            tv_liststate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_liststate);
            tv_hotelname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hotelname);
            tv_checkindate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_checkindate);
            tv_lastcheckindate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_lastcheckindate);

            btn_paynow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
            btn_cancellist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my cardview's xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/id_cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/stv_hotelname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_hotelicon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_hotelicon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_hotelname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_hotelicon"
                    android:text="佛山精神酒店"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlay_roomfee"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stv_roomfee"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="￥"
                    android:textColor="#F6070C"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_roomfee"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stv_roomfee"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#F6070C"
                    android:text="400"
                   />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/rlay_roomfee"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_liststate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#F6070C"
                    android:text="待支付"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/stv_hotelname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stv_checkindate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="入住时间："/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_checkindate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stv_checkindate"
                    android:text="1月10号"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stv_lastcheckindate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/stv_checkindate"
                    android:text="最晚入住时间："/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_lastcheckindate"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_checkindate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stv_lastcheckindate"
                    android:text="1月11号"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_cancellist"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="取消订单"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_paynow"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_cancellist"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="立即支付"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

when i note

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

it doesn't crash ,but the cardview does'show

Comment: show your error log ,xiong di :)

Comment: buddy，it does' not show any error log

Comment: buddy，i have finded the problem ，I forgot to initialize button.